# How do I Constantly update a pandas dataframe in NiceGUI?

Tags: python, pandas, nicegui

this is my first time doing any GUI in python so trying out niceGUI also for the first time.

I have a pandas dataframe that keeps updating based on certain conditions and im displaying it on NiceGUI using the table method. it displays fine but isn't updating when the dataframe updates. i tried using the .update call too but doesnt seem to change anything.

Am i doing something wrong or is there a certain way to do this?

Really massive newbie when it comes to any GUI work so any help will be appreciated!

I've even tried using a button that calls the update method to update the view of the dataframe but that isn't working either. I havn't been able to find another easier solution to this yet.

Edit: Also, any way to update the dataframe using changes in a .csv file will also work for me so if anyone can help in that regard, it will be appreciated too!

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.